# How to get a certain record after 'group by' operation

Tags: mysql, sql

Such as I have a table like :

[image]

I want to get the highest student from every class. How can I do?

```
select * 
from (select * 
      from stu 
      order by height desc) 
group by class_id
```

This doesn't work.
Ty

Comment: You need 2 copies of table - one is used for to get the highest height value in subquery, and the second to get the whole record which matches this value.

Comment: It doesn't work because it is broken SQL.  `select *` with `group by` just doesn't make sense and would return an error in almost all databases, including the most recent versions of MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM stu t1
JOIN ( SELECT class_id, MAX(height) height 
       FROM stu 
       GROUP BY class_id ) t2 USING (class_id, height)
```

If more than one student have the same maximal height over a class then all of them will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from stu s
where height = (select max(height) from stu s1
                where s1.class_id = s.class_id
                group by class_id)
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=827f16bc813d4b23cb72c044b45f85e1)

Answer (score 1):

You need  a subquery for max heigth and join

```
select * from stu 
inner join  (
  select class_id , max(height)  max_class_height
  from stu 
  group by  class_id

  ) t on t.class_id = stu.class_id and t.max_class_height = stu.height
```